# "Electronic Engineering" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you say **Electronic Engineering** in German? I've looked it up and it appears in some places just as "Elektronik", but it is like the "engineering" part there is missing. I'm just a beginner so I don't know much about the language so maybe that translation is correct.

Comment: I can speak German, but have no idea about the subject of Electronic Engineering. Linguee gives two translations: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=Electronic+Engineering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Electronic engineering* is a subfield of **electrical engineering** (*Elektrotechnik*). In Germany, usually people who do electronic engineering  are called *Elektrotechniker* or *Elektroingenieure* (if holding a university degree).

*Elektroniker* are usually people who just have a vocational training and install/repair radios, TVs, etc.

*Elektronik* usually only refers to plain "electronics", i.e. electronic circuits or elements.

Comment: Just to add a reference: The wikipedia articel about [Electrical engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_engineering) is in German about [Elektrotechnik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektrotechnik)

Comment: To add another data point: University majors for electrical engineering are usually called *Elektrotechnik* in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

You would say [*Elektronik*](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=electronic%20engineering&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on). The translation you found is indeed correct.

Comment: And how would just "Electronic" be translated?

Comment: Electronic is an adjective in English, so the equivalent adjective in German would be *elektronisch*. *Die Elektronik* is not an adjective in German, however. In fact, academic subjects are normally like the above word. If you were studying German, you would refer to German as *Germanistik* and not *Deutsch*.